# Running a K8s pod to support python virtual env

Tags: python, kubernetes, cloudcustodian

I am trying to create a Docker image along with K8s manifest, where i install some packages via pip in the image and later invoke that image in K8s to execute few cmds in the virtual env.

My Docker image looks like this

```
FROM cloudcustodian/c7n
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN python3 -m venv env && \
    source ./env/bin/activate && \
    python -m pip install install c7n && \
    python -m pip install install c7n-mailer

# RUN python -m venv custodian && \
#     source custodian/bin/activate && \
#     pip install c7n && \
#     pip install c7n-mailer
```

My K8s manifest is like this where i pass args via values.yaml file

```
            command: ["/bin/bash","-c" ]
            args:
            {{- range $.Values.args }}
            - {{ . | quote }}
            {{- end }}
```

My args are

```
args:
 - "source ./env/bin/activate && c7n-mailer --config /home/custodian/mailer.yml --update-lambda && custodian run -v -s /home/custodian/output /home/custodian/policies.yaml"
```

I tried alot permutations and combinations, but none worked

Typical error that i see is

```
kubectl logs -f custodian-cloud-custodian-cron-daily-policies-27973874-7csf5                     % at kube docker-desktop
/bin/bash: line 1: ./env/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

so the main question is how do u run a python virt env as k8s pod

Added sample code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the absolute path for this command `source ./env/bin/activate` in args